# Adding SSL Certificate to Keystore using AsyncHttpClient android

Tags: android, ssl

I want to add ssl certificate to my keystore using AsyncHttpclient. Now i'm accepting all certificate like below code,

```
  private AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient;
    private AppPreference mAppPreferences;
    private UserPreference mUserPreference;
    public CLHttpClient(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        MySSLSocketFactory socketFactory = null;
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);
            socketFactory = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
        asyncHttpClient.setTimeout(30 * 1000);
        if (socketFactory != null) {
            socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(MySSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            asyncHttpClient.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
        }
        asyncHttpClient.setMaxRetriesAndTimeout(1, 30000);
        asyncHttpClient.setUserAgent("android-async-http-1.4.9");
        mAppPreferences = new AppPreference(context);
        mUserPreference = new UserPreference(context);
    }
```

Where i'm accepting all the certificate like below,

```
socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(MySSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
```

But i dnt want to accept all the certificate. Instead of ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER i want to restrict it to accept my specific certificate. could you please suggest me to do this?
 I using  compile **'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'** in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my code like below,

```
private static final String TAG = CLHttpClient.class.getSimpleName();
        private Context context;
        private AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient;
        private AppPreference mAppPreferences;
        private UserPreference mUserPreference;
        public CLHttpClient(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            MySSLSocketFactory socketFactory = null;
            try {
    //            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    //            trustStore.load(null, null);
                socketFactory = new MySSLSocketFactory(buildKeyStore(context, R.raw.certificate_ca));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
            asyncHttpClient.setTimeout(30 * 1000);
            if (socketFactory != null) {
    //            socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(MySSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
                asyncHttpClient.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
            }
            asyncHttpClient.setMaxRetriesAndTimeout(1, 30000);
            asyncHttpClient.setUserAgent("android-async-http-1.4.9");
            mAppPreferences = new AppPreference(context);
            mUserPreference = new UserPreference(context);
        }
```

and the below methods,

```
 private static KeyStore buildKeyStore(Context context, int certRawResId) {
        // init a default key store
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = null;
        try {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            // read and add certificate authority
            Certificate cert = readCert(context, certRawResId);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", cert);
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return keyStore;
    }

    private static Certificate readCert(Context context, int certResourceId)  {
        // read certificate resource
        InputStream caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(certResourceId);

        Certificate ca=null;
        try {
            // generate a certificate
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                caInput.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return ca;
    }
```

It's works for me. Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(true,80,443);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.